# How to get user to enter in 24 hour format in BBC Basic

Tags: time, basic

I am making a program that will enable me to work out the avergae speed of something over a set distance

For this to work the user needs to input the start time and the end time.. I am not sure how you input time in a 24 hour format.

Furthermore I need to find the difference in the 2 times and then work out the speed.. which is distance/time taken.

Let's say distance was 1000 meters

Answer (score 0):

I lack a bbc basic compiler but you should create some like this

```
print str$(secondsinday("22:50:01")-secondsinday("17:09:17"))

sub secondsinday(t$)
return val(left$(t$,2))*3600+val(mid$(t$,4,2))*60+val(right$(t$,2))
end sub
```

I saw some bbc basic examples and the formula should be the same, only the function syntax is diffrent (I'll try and convert it after some research)